# How do I check if DataRow contains no nulls

Tags: c#

I have a DataRow and I need to make sure that it contains no nulls;
Came up with this, but I am not sure how to get the value from the DataColumn

```
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dr.Table.Columns)
        {
            if (dc == null && !(dc.ColumnName.Equals("id")))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (dc.ColumnName != "id" && dr[dc] == DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: Is there any benifit to this over calling [`DataRow.IsNull(DataColumn column)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ak67st4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(col => col.ColumnName != "id").Any(col => dr[col] == DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: EDIT: Did my cast in `VB.Net`, was just doing code in that and forgot to context switch :P